# Why is Spring Boot Monitoring and management using a remote shell is deprecated?

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I've made a small Spring Boot application and I was looking into the "put on production phase" and I thought that it would be a good idea to have the application run as a daemon on the server.

When writing the `systemd` service script the `ExecStart` was pretty straightforward, but it came to me that I had no idea how to stop it gracefully (ie not doing a `kill`). So after searching for a bit I came upon this : [Monitoring and management using a remote shell](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-remote-shell), and I thought that it was pretty neat, that I would connect to my application using `ssh` inside my `systemd` script and I would stop my application this way. But then I saw the dreadful "(deprecated)" next to the title.

So my question is : Why is it deprecated ?
I find it a bit overkill to have to call a HTTP service to do the "simple" thing of stopping application.

Thanks for your insight on the matter.

Comment: Just make the application executable and then the application acts as a script to stop/(re)start/kill the application. No ned to write your own scripts... See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-install  for more information. The answer your deprecated question it is deprecated because the project used ([CRaSHub](http://www.crashub.org)) has been dormant for about 2 years (you can read that as abandoned).

Comment: Very cool ! thanks a lot for pointing to the executable part.